# Gradle task is executed in parallel?

Tags: android, gradle, parallel-processing, task

Is the execution of  Gradle tasks in android stdio in in parallel?

Gradle  supports multiple projects to build.The build process actually performs a process of the  task set.

Two questions as following

1.In a single project, are the tasks  parallel?

2.In multiple project, are the tasks  parallel?

Comment: You might be interested in `@ParallelizableTask` annotation.  See here for an example: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-we-run-tasks-in-parallel-in-single-build-project/18321/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, tasks are not executed in parallel. Parallel execution can be enabled by the --parallel flag when the build is initiated. In parallel mode, the tasks of different projects (i.e. in a multi project build) are able to be executed in parallel. If a task is annotated with ParallelizableTask, it may also be executed in parallel with other tasks of the same project. See ParallelizableTask for more details on writing parallelizable tasks.

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html)

Comment: ParallelizableTask is deprecated now. Gradle has introduced a WorkerAPI to execute task in parallel
Here : https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/